# Wordpress: different single post template if subscriber is logged in

Tags: wordpress

How can I "tell" Wordpress to choose a different single post template if the user making the request happens to be a logged in subscriber?

This is what I want to do.
Our company distributes products. 
The general public can check out the individual products (single posts) and have access to some information (public pricing, etc.).

The plan is to manually add our resellers as subscribers in WP admin, let them log in as subscribers in our website, and then they would be able to see a *similar* single post, but with some more information thrown in (reseller pricing, volume discounts, links to service manuals, stuff like that).

Is this easy to accomplish?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this with the built-in WordPress function [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

From a high level, I would actually create a code snippet in my `single.php` template like so:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    include 'single_subscriber.php';
}
else {
    include 'single_visitor.php';
}
```

Then you can actually keep `single.php` clean and simple.  But put your actual templates for different users in different files.

Of course, if you have common functionality or logic it would be best to do all of those common things in `single.php` where possible, and perhaps tweak my example to only **add** more items using that built-in function.

Comment: That code seems to work and change templates. It does redirect the logged in user to another single post template file.
However... and it's a big HOWEVER, I'm affraid... now the logged out users (i.e. the rest of the world) can't see the post at all. It crashes with the following message:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 122880 bytes) in /home/jailb8/public_html/wp-content/themes/audiolog/single.php on line 174

(whatever this means... checked out line 174, not sure what it's complaining about).

Where in the file would you include this code?

Comment: Figured it out!
I was pasting the code at the beginning of the single.php file, but then I left the rest of the code in. I believe this created some kind of recursive loop as the single.php was being called continuously (if you happened to be logged out). 

Now if the user is logged in, one template is used (single-subscribed.php). If it's not, I use single-regular.php).
The single.php just includes the above code.

However, I will look into what you suggest, and just add what's needed. Seems like a clean solution. Even though I have to remove other stuff as well. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you comfortable with PHP?  What you'd have to do is find the template directory and edit (or create) single.php and use `get_template_part` to display the correct single.php template:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) :
                <?php get_template_part( 'single' ); ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'single', 'guest' ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load     up the comment template
                if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                    comments_template();
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

P.S. I copied that single.php page from https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/single.php